# Think up algorithm: Calculate full earnings for every company

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, algorithm, treeview

I have a TreeView with companies. Every company can have subcompanies, every subcompany can have subcompanies and this can continue to infinity.
Every company have own earnings, and have FullEarnings which equals sum of all subcompanies this company.

I need to calculate earnings for every company if known own earnings every company.

Example:

```
CompanyName  | OwnEarnings | FullEarnings
 -Company1   | 25K$        | 53K$
 --Company2  | 13K$        | 18K$
 ---Company3 | 5K$
 --Company4  | 10K$
```

I have a database column ParentID, which link to id parent company.

How i can do it? Maybe by recursion?

Comment: I believe I have solved the issue below, let me know if you have any issues, questions, or concerns!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way or another, you will need to recursively update your table.

In your case that will look something like:

```
with C as
(
  select T.Id,
         T.Earnings,
         T.Id as RootID
  from T
  union all
  select T.Id,
         T.Earnings,
         C.RootID
  from T
    inner join C 
      on T.ParentId = C.Id
)
select T.Id,
       T.ParentId,
       T.CompanyName,
       T.Earnings,
       S.FullEarnings
from T
  inner join (
             select RootID,
                    sum(Earnings) as FullEarnings
             from C
             group by RootID
             ) as S
    on T.Id = S.RootID
order by T.Id
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88be6/6)

In order to update, you will want to change out the select with an `update` query as shown in this [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88be6/2)

Comment: Maybe, the resolved is true. But i must bind query to database from C# code behind.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()`? [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx)